# Revert back the hidden column in 2FA enabled list

Tags: sharepoint-server

Here i have a question, i.e., I have developed a farm solution for 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) which helps to store the passwords in secure way.(2FA works as the passwords in the Password wallet List of SharePoint will be visible only after entering the OTP(One-Time-Password), While we enable this 2fa feature we provide the Internal name of the Field (it is like which field should be protected with 2FA) after entering the field name (column name) the column will be hidden from the list and it won't revert back even if we disable the 2FA feature...is there any way to revert back that Hidden column as before without 2FA feature(means Deactivating 2FA))?